# Select html files in a folder

Tags: c#

Using "folderBrowserDialog1" can i select only HTML files in a folder.

My code is like this :

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
   if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
       MessageBox.Show("Files found: " + files.Length.ToString(), "Message");
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is `folderBrowserDialog1`?

Comment: use folderBrowserDialog1.Filter = "*.html"

Answer (score 5):

Use: [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63.aspx)

> Returns a file list from the current directory matching the given
>   search pattern.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("*.html");
```

Or if you only want to `html` files to be available for selection you can use:

[OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx)

```
folderBrowserDialog1.Filter = "*.html | *.htm";
```

Comment: Am gettig error like this : Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog' does not contain a definition for 'Filter' and no extension method 'Filter' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Sushmitha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Gutenberg\Gutenberg\Gutenberg\Form1.cs 58 34 Gutenberg

Comment: Is there any other option?

Comment: Use OpenFileDialog instead.

Comment: I wanted to select more than 2 HTML files from folder. Is that possible

Comment: Use the [```MultiSelect```](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect.aspx) property on the ```OpenFileDialog```.